# I'm trying to make a discord bot that searches wikipedia

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot that lets people search wikipedia, for example someone sends /wikipedia [their search] and it searches for it and sends the result into the chat. This is my first time trying to make a bot. This is what I got so far but I constantly get error.

```
import wikipedia
def search():
    search = wikipedia.summary(question, sentances=2)
    return search

[some other code]

@client.command()
async def wikipedia(ctx,*,question):
    await ctx.send(search())
```

I get errors that say

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: 
 AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your function name has the same name as the library itself. So when you call `wikipedia.summary`, your code thinks that you're trying to access the summary property of your `wikipedia` function.

As far as I know, you have two options to fix this. You could either

- change the name of the command
- use the `import x as y` in order to change the name of the wikipedia library

For the first one, you can change it to `wikipedia_search` instead of `wikipedia`, so it'd look like this:

```
@client.command()
async def wikipedia_search(ctx,*,question):
    await ctx.send(search())
```

For the second option, you can change your import line from `import wikipedia` to `import wikipedia as wikipedia_lib`. And then when you're trying to use the library, you can do `wikipedia_lib.summary(question, sentances=2)` instead.

Also, as a side note, you misspelled `sentences` as `sentances`, which will probably cause an error. Hence, I'd advise that you change that.

Comment: Yes that worked! Although I did change the code a bit to 
`@client.command()
async def wikipedia_search(ctx,*,question):
    await ctx.send(wikipedia.summary(question))`